# Creating a file of max length characters, with a word inserted at random locations x amount of times

Tags: python, string, random, python-3.7

I am able to create the random data file but when trying to insert the word at random locations x amount of times, the length of the file becomes greater than the max length passed in.

I have tried creating a file with random characters - length of word*amount of times it needs to be inserted and then adding it to the random locations but that just led to it being appended to the end of the file.

```py
def gen_file(word:str, frequency:int, maxlength:int):
    contents = ''
    i = 0

    while i < frequency:
        for x in range(0, maxlength):
            ran_num = random.randint(0, maxlength-1)
            if x == ran_num:
                contents = contents + word
                i = i+1
            else:
                contents = contents + random.choice(string.ascii_letters)

    file = open("new.txt","w")
    file.write(file_contents)
    file.close()
```

If I call the function as gen_file('hello', 3, 5000). I expect the output file to be 5000 characters long with 'hello' inserted at 3 random locations but I get an output file that ranges anywhere from 10,000 - 20,000 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is right at the top of your control flow:

```
while i < frequency:
    for x in range(0, maxlength):
```

For *each* of the 3 insertions, you generate 5000 `x` characters.  Instead, you need to choose three random locations within *one* set of 5000.  I suggest that you do this by choosing the three random locations at the beginning.  Sort those in order.  Then write your file, keeping track of the index position.  Whenever you reach the next position in your random list, stop to insert "hello".

Does that get you going?